# three.js: Rotate around origin after panning camera

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js, pan

I have a plane/board, with a grid, that is about 1100 x 1100. I have panning, zooming, and rotating working except for the fact that the board moves back to the center of the screen after it has been panned. So, if I don't pan the board at all then everything works. After I pan the board it moves back to the center of the screen when I try to rotate it. I cannot figure out how to change the origin of the camera so that it rotates around the center of the board. It seems like it rotates around the center of the camera.

var radius = 1500, theta = 45 * 0.5, onMouseDownTheta = 45 * 0.5;
var fov = 45;
var mouse2D = new THREE.Vector3(0, 10000, 0.5);

cameraX = radius * Math.sin(THREE.Math.degToRad(theta));
cameraY = 1000;
cameraZ = radius * Math.cos(THREE.Math.degToRad(theta));

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.set(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

render();

ThreeBoard.prototype.render = function() {

```
mouse2D.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
mouse2D.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

// rotate
if (isMouseDown && isShiftPressed && !isCtrlPressed) {
    theta = ((event.pageX - mouse2D.x) * 0.5) + onMouseDownTheta;

    cameraX = radius * Math.sin(THREE.Math.degToRad(theta));
    cameraZ = radius * Math.cos(THREE.Math.degToRad(theta));

    camera.position.set(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ);

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

// pan
if (isMouseDown && isShiftPressed && isCtrlPressed) {
    theta = ((event.pageX - mouse2D.x) * 0.5) + onMouseDownTheta;

    cameraX += 10 * mouse2D.x;
    // cameraY += 10;
    cameraZ -= 10 * mouse2D.y;

    camera.position.set(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ);

    // camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

};

Comment: Have you considered using `THREE.OrbitControls` instead?

Comment: I have, but it didn't work out too well. I don't remember why. I try it again.

Comment: Oh wait, I haven't used OrbitControls. When I glanced at it I thought it said TrackballControls. I have setup up my code to use TrackballControls again. The problem I am having is the board still doesn't rotate correctly, but atleast now it doesn't jump back to the middle of the screen.