# How to update the center of a model after a panning operation in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, camera, rotation, three.js

I'm an experience Javascript programmer but a Three.js noob.  I've started a project based on the Molecule example found in the Three.js repo:

http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_molecules

The code for the pan operation looks like this:

```
this.panCamera = (function(){

    var mouseChange = new THREE.Vector2(),
        objectUp = new THREE.Vector3(),
        pan = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function () {

        mouseChange.copy( _panEnd ).sub( _panStart );

        if ( mouseChange.lengthSq() ) {

            mouseChange.multiplyScalar( _eye.length() * _this.panSpeed );

            pan.copy( _eye ).cross( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseChange.x );
            pan.add( objectUp.copy( _this.object.up ).setLength( mouseChange.y ) );

            _this.object.position.add( pan );
            // _this.target.add( pan );
            _this.target.position.add(pan);

            if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

                _panStart.copy( _panEnd );

            } else {

                _panStart.add( mouseChange.subVectors( _panEnd, _panStart ).multiplyScalar( _this.dynamicDampingFactor ) );

            }

        }
    }
```

As the code is currently structured, the center of the model is not updated after the pan operation.  So initially, when you rotate the model in any direction, it spins nicely about it's center like a sphere rotating in place.  However after a pan operation, instead of spinning around its center point *it spins around the *old* center point before the pan operation*.  This makes the model look like a satellite orbiting around the old center point instead of revolving pleasantly about its center.  (Think of a ball being swung around you at the end of a string.)

_this.object is a ThreeJS PerspectiveCamera object 
_this.target is a 3D vector that I *believe* is the model but I'm not quite sure.

I found this SO post but it is unanswered:

[three.js: Rotate around origin after panning camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204720/three-js-rotate-around-origin-after-panning-camera)

What do I need to change to update the center of the model after the pan operation?

Comment: You appear to have a fundamental misunderstanding when you write: "when you rotate the model in any direction". You are not rotating the model with the mouse, you are rotating the _camera_. When you pan with the mouse, the camera translates parallel to "screen-space", and the `target`, the point around which the camera orbits, translates an equal amount.

Comment: @WestLangley Right.  Someone in the ThreeJS chat room educated me to that.  It looks like I'll have to rotate the model and pan and zoom the camera.